# Capital letter for figures

Tags: captions

I have two figures which I want to show up in my list of figures as 2A and 2B. Additionally, I want them both to have a caption. Everything workes fine, except that they show up as 1a and 1b.
Here is the code that I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfloat}                           
       
\begin{document}


\begin{subfigures}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{ER-FIG2A}
  \caption{\label{first}Caption text.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{ER-FIG2B}
  \caption{\label{second}Caption text.} 
\end{figure}
\end{subfigures}

\end{document}
```

Edit: I added the whole code which I am using.
I already googled, however none of the suggestions in older threats worked out for me.
I am grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: If the two figures really have something in common, I'd recommend using subfigure from the subcaption package and to give them a common caption. As far as I can see, the `subfloat` package hasn't been maintained for 18 years. Not that this makes it obsolete, but there are better and clearer ways to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the documentation for `subfloat` (type `texdoc subfloat` at a command line or go to https://texdoc.org/ to look up the documentation), section 4 talks about how to change the label format. For your needs, you would do

```
\renewcommand*\thesubfloatfigure{\themainfigure(\Alph{subfloatfigure})}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll read through these sources. Additionally, your suggestion worked.